# "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error to launch a webserver with private IP

Tags: networking, vpn, aws

I need to create an EC2 instance (Linux web server)
with a private IP address (10.*x*.*x*.*x*)
that can be accessible via Corporate VPN only.

I created a private VPC CIDR 10.10.10.0/24,
and created an EC2 instance that doesn't have a public IP address. 
I even assigned a primary IP 10.10.10.8 when creating an EC2. 
The inbound security groups are restricted to the VPN IP range only.

I installed the web server in EC2, and when I tried to launch in the web browser via VPN, I got the error "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

I'm able to launch the website in the browser if I assign a public IP
to the EC2 instance, but this is not what I wanted.

Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: What's linking the Corporate VPN to the VPC in AWS so the packets can travel from the Corporate VPN to AWS and back?

Comment: where's the configuration? I haven't configured this part

Comment: If your Corporate VPN has not been configure to know how to reach the VPC and EC2 server in AWS, then the server most likely won't be reachable through the VPN.  Configuring your Corporate VPN to have a link to this new AWS VPC is probably the topic for another question, but it may be best to coordinate with your company's network folks who manage the VPN.